# Filtering dataframe by comparing two dataframe columns containing different formatted phone numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe, df1, containing a list of US phone numbers in the following format:
Area code + phone numbers

And it contains international phone numbers

This dataframe is a couple of hundred rows long

```
df1['phoneNumber'] = ['123456789', '1115559999','1112223333', '442071231234']
```

I have another dataframe, df2, containing millions of phone records in several different formats such as:
Country code + area code + phone number

Arbitrary dial out number from business such as "9" + area code + phone number

International phone numbers

```
df2['phoneNumber'] = ['1123456789', '81115559999','442071231234','1111111111', '0133344556677']
```

I would like to filter down the larger dataframe by checking whether a phone number from the smaller dataframe is in the larger dataframe because the larger dataset will sometimes have a longer phone number string.

Is this possible? I've been using a for loop and functions to filter the data but it is taking three or four minutes to loop and filter through a million records.

Thank you.

**Edit:**
My current code is something along the lines of this:

```python
matching_numbers_list = []

def match_numbers(phone_number, phone_number_li):
    matching_number = next((row for row in phone_number_li if row in phone_number), None)

    matching_numbers_list.append(matching_number)


# code worked faster when I didn't use entire df in function
phone_number_list = df1['PhoneNumber']

[match_numbers(row[0], phone_number_list) for row in zip(df2['PhoneNumber'])]


# add additional column with matched numbers
df2['MatchedNumbers'] = matching_numbers_list

# inner join based on the matched numbers
filtered_df = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='inner', left_on='MatchedNumbers', right_on='PhoneNumber')
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: do you know the length of country_code, area_code and phone_number? And are they fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do a partial string match of every phone number in `df2` to the list in `df1`.

```py
df2[df2['phoneNumber'].str.contains('|'.join(df1['phoneNumber']))]
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you!
In conjunction with this code, is there a way to add the matching string from df1 into the filtered results or will I have to do add it via a for loop?